# How to secure CodeIgniter URI segments when allowing all Characters with Oracle DB

Tags: php, oracle, security, codeigniter, escaping

I am getting URI segments from CodeIgniter and using them in query to an Oracle database.  What is the way to secure these segments?  As I cannot find a Oracle escape method for php (MySQL escape method in php is mysql_real_escape_string()).

And on a side note, is the security in CodeIgniter really as insanely dangerous as they try to tell you in the config file. I am of the thinking it is safe so long as you escape these URI segments appropriately in any query with the database system you are using, but I don't know if I am correct.

Thanks.

Comment: It's been a while since i last took a glance at CI, but isn't it's ORM escaping values automatically? In any way there is still old buddy addslashes. It's not that good and doesn't defend absolutely, but still

Comment: And there is escape method yet.. Well, i'm not quite sure, but i think you should probably read some docs on CI offsite

Comment: Use always prepared statement so you can bind the values without having fear about SQL injection especially when you work on Oracle. Using prepared statement instead of plain SQL is also well recommended for performance since the query will be cached on the db side

Comment: +1 for the prepared statements. Not only the bind variables are 100% safe and allow the query to be cached in Oracle but they also let Oracle skip the costly hard parse everytime. Here you can find a quick overview of the benefits of using bind variables: http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend using CI query bindings

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?"; 

$this->db->query($sql, array($yourSegment1, $yourSegment2, $yourSegment3));
```

Comment: This doesn't work as you'd hope with Oracle. That code will allow "binding" of a string like `' OR 1=1 --` and simply add it into the query which you really don't want. Oracle bind variables don't seem to work natively in CI without some modification of `oci8_driver.php` and some other DB driver files